# Using enumerated class values to call an array element in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, struct, enums

My code:

Enumerations.h

```
#ifndef ENUMERATIONS_H
#define ENUMERATIONS_H

enum class Employees
{
    ERIC,
    RYAN,
    EMILY
};

#endif
```

Structs.h

```
struct Employee
{
    std::string name;
    double wage;
};
```

Review.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Enumerations.h"
#include "Structs.h"

Employee employeeArray[3];

    employeeArray[0] = { "Eric Sartor", 18.75 };
    employeeArray[1] = { "Ryan Ulch", 20.36 };
    employeeArray[2] = { "Emily Gover", 18.75 };

cout << employeeArray[Employees::RYAN].name;
```

So I'm trying to do something that I read in my C++ tutorial, where you call an array element (a struct) via an enumerated value.  Earlier in the tutorial, it's recommended that if you compiler is C++11 compliant (which mine is) that is it better to use an enumerated class rather than a regular enumeration.

I'm noticing that when trying to call my element from my array via the `Employees::RYAN` enumerated value, it gives me an error that says "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type".  If I remove the class keyword from my enumeration so it's just `enum Employees` and I change the array index to `RYAN`, it works fine.  Am I missing something, or does this just not work with an enumerated class?

Hopefully I was clear enough.  In the example on the tutorial, he actually DID NOT use an enumerated class, just a regular enumeration, even though he explicitly said earlier to always do that if you can...hopefully someone can clarify this for me!

Comment: Try using employeeArray[static_cast<int>(Employees::RYAN)]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An enumeration with an *enum-key* of `class` or `struct` is a *scoped enumeration*. Scoped enumerations don't have an implicit conversion to `int`.

> The value of an enumerator or an object of an unscoped enumeration type is converted to an integer by integral promotion (4.5). *[ Example:*
>
> ```c++
> enum color { red, yellow, green=20, blue };
> color col = red;
> color* cp = &col;
> if (*cp == blue) // ...
> ```
>
> makes color a type describing various colors, and then declares `col` as an object of that type, and `cp` as a pointer to an object of that type. The possible values of an object of type `color` are `red`, `yellow`, `green`,
>   `blue`; these values can be converted to the integral values `0`, `1`, `20`, and `21`. Since enumerations are distinct types, objects of type `color` can be assigned only values of type `color`.
>
> ```c++
> color c = 1; // error: type mismatch,
> // no conversion from int to color
> int i = yellow; // OK: yellow converted to integral value 1
> // integral promotion
> ```
>
> **Note that this implicit `enum` to `int` conversion is not provided for a scoped enumeration:**
>
> ```c++
> enum class Col { red, yellow, green };
> int x = Col::red; // error: no Col to int conversion
> Col y = Col::red;
> if (y) { } // error: no Col to bool conversion
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

You can explicitly cast the enumerator to `int` instead:

```c++
cout << employeeArray[static_cast<int>(Employees::RYAN)].name;
```

Comment: That pretty well solves that.  In your opinion, is using a standard enum any worse than using an enumerated class?  I'd hate to have to cast all my enums for use with arrays, it seems like it'd be easier to just remove the `class`.

Comment: @eric The main differences between scoped and unscoped enums is the implicit conversion and the fact that for scoped enums you need to qualify the name (i.e Color::Ryan not Ryan). So since you need your enumerators to be implicitly convertible to integral types, use an unscoped enum.

Answer (score 0):

From the C++ Standard (5.2.1 Subscripting)

> 1 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is
>   a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type
>   “array of T” or “pointer to T” and the other shall have **unscoped
>   enumeration or integral type**....

There is no implicit conversion from a scoped enumeration to an integral type.

If you want to use a scoped enumeration as an index you have explicitly cast it to some integral type. 
For example

```
cout << employeeArray[static_cast<int>( Employees::RYAN )].name;
```